# facebook: how to retrive my own photos in php?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-permissions

I am trying to display my own photos form my facebook page.
I am using the latest FB SDK.

I have various photos in my FB.

```
<?php
require '../src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '699018806799368',
  'secret' => '',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    $photos = $facebook->api('me/photos');
    print_r($photos);

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $statusUrl = $facebook->getLoginStatusUrl();
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

  <body>
    <h1>php-sdk</h1>
    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div>
        Check the login status using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
        <a href="<?php echo $statusUrl; ?>">Check the login status</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
        <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>PHP Session</h3>
    <pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <h3>You</h3>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">
      <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
    <?php else: ?>
      <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
    <?php endif ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

However $photos is empty: what Am I doing wrong ?
Do I need any special rights for my application ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the permissions in the App Settings is for the App Centre only, the permissions will actually be asked in the app only if you add them in your login code.

So, replace-

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
```

with-

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'user_photos'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```